# Jquery auto trigger event on checkbox unchecks the control

Tags: javascript, jquery, checked, event-triggers

Here is my html and javascript, want to auto check on click of button and oncheck want to trigger some more actions. Tried with 'click' and 'change' event

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){


$('#4').on('click', function(){
    $('#1').prop('checked', true).trigger('click');
    $('#2').prop('checked', true).trigger('click');
});

$('#1').on('click', function(){
    if($('#1').is(':checked')){
        $('#3').prop('disabled','disabled');
    }
    else{
    $('#3').prop('disabled','');
    }
         });
       });
 </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <label>
      <input id="1" type="checkbox" value="">Yes</label><br><br>
         <label>
       <input id="2" type="checkbox" value="">NO</label><br><br>
     <label>
      <input id="3" type="text" value="Hello World">Yes</label><br><br>

     <input id="4" type="button" value="Submit"/><br><br>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you started.

```js
var onYesChecked = function() {
  if($('#1').is(':checked')){
    $('#3').prop('disabled',true);
  } else{
    $('#3').prop('disabled',false);
  }
};

var onNoChecked = function() {
 // your NoChecked logic here
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#4').on('click', function(){
     // `.prop('checked', true)` will check the checkbox.
      // Triggering click will immediately uncheck the checkbox 
      // (simulating a user click).
      // $('#1').prop('checked', true).trigger('click');
      // $('#2').prop('checked', true).trigger('click');
      
      $('#1').prop('checked', true);
      $('#2').prop('checked', true);
      onYesChecked();
      onNoChecked();
  });

  $('#1').on('click', onYesChecked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input id="1" type="checkbox" value="">Yes
</label>
<br><br>
<label>
  <input id="2" type="checkbox" value="">NO
</label>
<br><br>
<label>
  <input id="3" type="text" value="Hello World">Yes
</label>
<br><br>
<input id="4" type="button" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: All my actions on controls are dynamically driven, I bind to the events on load of the page.How to use .trigger('click') for my scenarios?